# Flutter how to name a function then pass it through another function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am brand new to Flutter and come from an Angular / React background.

I am trying to find the correct syntax to store a function within a variable and pass that function to another function.

Here is my code:

The negativeBtnFunc is saying "Expected to find '}'." but I don't see where I am missing that.

The positiveBtnFunc seems to be working just fine.

```
onPressed: () {
    negativeBtnFunc() => {
        RouteGenerator().hasAcceptedTAndC = false;
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
           SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          exit(0);
        }
    };
    positiveBtnFunc() => {};
    return showAlertDialog(
           context,
           kTermsAlertTitle,
           kTermsAlertBody,
           kAlertPosOk,
           positiveBtnFunc,
           kAlertNegCloseApp,
           negativeBtnFunc
    );
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

In dart following code is returning a `Set`. So both the buttons code is invalid. Unlike JavaScript you don't use curly `{}` after `=>` unless you want to return a `Set` or a `Map`. Anything after fat-arrow is considered as a value.

```dart
// invalid ...
negativeBtnFunc() => {
    RouteGenerator().hasAcceptedTAndC = false;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
       SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
       exit(0);
    }
}
```

To a pass function you can do it this way:

```dart
onPressed: () {
    Function negativeBtnFunc = () {
        RouteGenerator().hasAcceptedTAndC = false;
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
           SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          exit(0);
        }
        return;
    };
    Function positiveBtnFunc = () {
        return;
    };
    return showAlertDialog(
           context,
           kTermsAlertTitle,
           kTermsAlertBody,
           kAlertPosOk,
           positiveBtnFunc,
           kAlertNegCloseApp,
           negativeBtnFunc
    );
},
```

Comment: Hi another person suggested to place "void" in front of the function, I did that and the syntax error was removed. Do you see any side effects of that not working and that your answer is better?

Comment: When trying the "Function" it gives me this error -> "This function has a return type of 'Function', but doesn't end with a return statement.  Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'."

Comment: Where did you put `void` & which other changes have you made?

Comment: Where did you put `Function` & which other changes have you made? I've tried my code on dartpad and it's working fine for me.

Comment: I added a screenshot to show what my IDE says above ^

Comment: Oh okay. You can put empty `return;` in the end. I've updated my answer. That line is showing a warning, and that too not a critical one.

Comment: Also if you prefer to use void, then you can swap out `Function` with `void` in my code & in that case it won't complain about `return;`

Comment: Sweet so I rechecked your syntax without the return and it now works - I didn't have the 
Function functionName = (); That's what I was missing. Thanks for your answer

Comment: So you don't need that return in there FYI - your answer was correct the first time. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Cool, No issues. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over this, the returntype would be a `Map<dynamic,dynamic>` because `{}` is how you declare a Map in Dart

```
   negativeBtnFunc() => {};
```

I think the problem is, that you didn't declare "negativeBtnFunc" as Function. The following code should work but doesn't really make sense. If you need this function anywhere else outside the `onPressed`, you would need to declare it in a bigger scope.

```
   onPressed: () {
        Function negativeBtnFunc = () {
            RouteGenerator().hasAcceptedTAndC = false;
            if (Platform.isAndroid) {
               SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
            } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
              exit(0);
            }  
        }; 
        negativeBtnFunc();
        Function positiveBtnFunc = () {};
        
        //I think this should be a function aswell. But I don't know if your onPressed has a return type.
        return showAlertDialog(
               context,
               kTermsAlertTitle,
               kTermsAlertBody,
               kAlertPosOk,
               positiveBtnFunc,
               kAlertNegCloseApp,
               negativeBtnFunc
        );
     },
```

Assuming that the onPressed comes from one of those buttons, this is how I would do it:

```
   onPressed: () {        
        RouteGenerator().hasAcceptedTAndC = false;
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          exit(0);
        }    
        showDialog();
     },
```

If this didn't help, would you mind telling me what the `onPressed` function is attached to and what you are trying to achieve? I don't quite understand why you would want to use the functions of 2 buttons on a single `onPressed` event

Comment: When I posted my answer, your answer was not there. I checked you deleted. Np :)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that in my initial answer, I didn't get the problem :D

Comment: I am passing the function to a reusable alert dialog and only want to invoke the function if that button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Spoke to a coworker and they told me I was just missing the "void" in front of the function

```
onPressed: () {
    void negativeBtnFunc() => {
        RouteGenerator().hasAcceptedTAndC = false;
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
           SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          exit(0);
        }
    };
    void positiveBtnFunc() => {};
    return showAlertDialog(
           context,
           kTermsAlertTitle,
           kTermsAlertBody,
           kAlertPosOk,
           positiveBtnFunc,
           kAlertNegCloseApp,
           negativeBtnFunc
    );
 },
```

When trying to place Function in front of the negativeBtnFunc this is what I see:
[image]

Comment: Anything after fat-arrow is considered as a value in dart. It should throw syntax error.